# Como Converter uma String em uma Data no C#

Tags: c#

estou tentando construir um método que receba 4 parâmetros: “nome” que será um texto, “data_nascimento” que será uma data, “profissao” que será um texto e “numero_calcado” que será um número inteiro. O Método deve retornar um texto com a frase (exemplo) “Bruno, nasceu em 18/02/1980, é programador e calça 46.”.

Entretanto, não consigo converter a String da Data para o Formato de Data.

Tentei pelo Convert.toDateTime mas não foi.

Como seria a forma correta?

Tentei dessa forma:

```
  //Data de Nascimento
    Console.Write("Insira a Data de Nascimento do Cliente: ");
    string data_nascimento = Console.ReadLine();  
    Convert.ToDateTime(data_nascimento);
```

Tentei novamente dessa forma:

```
//Data de Nascimento
  Console.Write("Insira a Data de Nascimento do Cliente: ");
  string data_string = Console.ReadLine();  
  DateTime data_nascimento = DateTime.Parse(data_string);
```

Consegui converter, mas o Console retornou a Hora depois da Data e eu não quero a hora, como posso remover?

Minhas perguntas estão sendo fechadas quase que imediatamente pelos moderadores e eu não estou entendendo o porquê, comecei a participar aqui hoje.

Obrigado!